# Facebook SDK 3.21.1 deprecated methods error

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, sdk, cocoapods

I installed facebook SDK via cocoapods and after building my project that includes facebook sdk it shows 4 errors of deprecated methods in iOS 8.

I think i have the last version of facebook SDK (3.21.1) so i don't know that the problem is.I want to know why i have the problem and how to solve it, I don't need to know a workaround.

I understand that the methods are deprecated but if facebook sdk is updated they should update that methods too.

You can see in the image the errors i get

[image: Errors]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because Facebook is using deprecated methods on it SDK, probably because they have to support older versions of iOS.

You can change your `Podfile` to ignore the warnings in a dependency, as mentioned on [the docs](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#inhibit_all_warnings_bang):

```
pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK', :inhibit_warnings => true
```

You can also ignore warnings from all dependencies:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '8.0'
inhibit_all_warnings!

pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK'
```

Comment: Thanks @Marcelo Fabri , the first command removed the warning of the dependency. But i wonder if in the future it will not show warnings on my app.

Answer (score 0):

It's an example from the Facebook SDK right!? I mean right now it's just deprecated but not unsupported. So they can still use it in their example. However you shouldn't use it in your project! There are a lot of workarounds online in order to manage the necessary tasks without using the deprecated methods.

If this would be your project the warning would have been there already without the use of the FB SDK, since it's iOS related and not FB related.

Comment: Yes it's the exemple os Facebook SDK! just started the app, build and run and got this warnings

Comment: Well as I've already mentioned, it's just an example and they will probably update it in a new SDK version. Right now it's not so crucial, since it's still working. Nevertheless I would recommend using the posted alternatives for your own project rather than using deprecated functions. A huge company such as Facebook needs also time to update their SDK. They won't publish an update just because of a couple of deprecated functions within their samples.

Comment: Yes i understand that.I don't think i will use that methods.It's just the warnings that bother me. Thank you

Comment: I can understand your point. I mean it's always weird if you look at a sample or something similar and then you get warnings or even errors. You would expect a properly working setup, but this happens from time to time ;)

Answer (score 0):

These items were deprecated by Apple, not Facebook.

For the device orientation, try using [UITraitCollection](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITraitSet_ClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014202-CH1-SW14) to get information about the device's orientation ie:

```
self.traitCollection.verticalSizeClass
self.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass
```

For NSGregorianCalendar, try using NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian

Comment: I understand the items were deprecated by Apple. Thanks for you help